# Fontawesome & Drupal 7 - need a hint to make icons appear

Tags: drupal-7, font-awesome

I am using font awesome in a free Drupal theme - Alpha Responsive.  I am also editing content through the Drupal module WYSWIG which uses CKEditor 3.6.6.2.7696 (anything later seems to break Drupal).

This is the issue I observe.  I can insert icons in content up to a point on the list included in the fontawesome.css and then the icons just don't show up.

Moreover, I am pretty sure that one of the misbehaving icons did show up earlier this evening.  But -- as the list of icons in the theme was not complete, and I thought it may be an economical solution to replace the fontawesome.css and the fonts directory with the latest from the Fonts Awesome site. This did not work and I returned the originals and then encountered the problem of only 90% of the list working.

These are the checks I have carried out:
The missing icons do not show up as a pseudo element when I use "Inspect Element"
I have physically cleaned off any trace to old Font Awesome files
I have tried in Chrome and Firefox
I have tested up and down the list so I know where the list stops working
I have cleared the caches on Drupal and Firefox.

The only thing I have not done that I can think of is to rebuild the entire site. I could delete the theme but it includes a Nvivo slider and I am loathe to rebuild that.  Any ideas on what to check before I wipe the slate clean?

And while I am asking, what is the best way to update the fontawesome.css when new icons come out? It is not good practice to update the theme in case the owners of the them update it and break my changes.  I am not sure how to add the additional fonts to a subtheme.

I would appreciate any patient replies that will help my debugging or set me on the right path.  For people who detest noobes, sorry I am one and ill temper won't educate me faster.  Please ignore me. I wish you a good day and prosperous 2015 all the same.

---

For what it is worth, I have done a clean install of Drupal 7 and installed Alpha Responsive (with the site's subtheme). The icons load upto "bomb" and then not. So I overwrote /fonts and fontawesome.css and I get the same result.  It seems not to have been my meddling - any other ideas?

---

I have just found a reference elsewhere that some icons in 4.2 are not working. This may be my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Font awesome icons are working now as expected.